# Fetch Json data is not displayed

Tags: reactjs

So i have a function that returns a list of users in json.
I want to print the list, string by string like:
User1
User2
User3
but the output is nothing.
I just start using react, any help?

```
export default function Users() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [UsersRow, setUsersRow] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/users", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "pass " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        setUsersRow(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
        window.location.replace("/")
      })
  }, [])

  if (UsersRow === undefined) {
    return <div />
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableBody>
            {UsersRow.map(row => (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left">{row.user}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The backend function returns a json like this:

```
[
  "User1", 
  "User2", 
  "User3"
]
```

Backend func:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def user_list():
    list_1 = []
    users = ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew')

    for user in users:
        list_1.append(str(user).split(",")[0].split("=")[1].encode())
    return jsonify(list_1)
```

Comment: can you console.log(data) and see if you are getting it ? the code looks okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backend returns this:

```
[
  "User1", 
  "User2", 
  "User3"
]
```

Then, you would render like this:

```
<TableBody>
    {UsersRow.map(user => (
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell align="left">{user}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

There wouldn't be a `user` property on `row`.